# Google Maps renders gray/beige box

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to embed a Google Map by using the v3 api:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="map"></div>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=mykey&sensor=false&region=DE"></script>
    <script>
      new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('div.map'), {
        zoom: 4, center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is that it successfully loads all ajax and renders them into the **div.map** but the map is beige/gray and the controls are missing.

Note:

- **key=mykey** is a placeholder for my api key
- **document.querySelector** returns the matching element node and work on my browser
- omitting the map type is allowed as **ROADMAP** is the default
- you do not have to put the logic into a **load** event wrapper as it is at the end of the doc

So please do not advice anything of the aboves - I tried them already!

So what am I doing wrong?

Bodo

Comment: What determines the size of the map div?

Comment: @geocodezip in the original example there is a bootstrap span8 for the width and I self give it a height of 400px

Comment: @geocodezip have just tried to remove the classes and put it somewhere without css restrictions and the result was the same. Just the box was bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mapTypeId is required per the [documnetation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)

mapTypeId   MapTypeId   The initial Map mapTypeId. **Required.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="map" style="height:500px; wiodth:600px;"></div>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&region=DE"></script>
    <script>
      new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('div.map'), {
        zoom: 4, center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_documentQuerySelector.html)

Comment: You where right about that. V3 Experimental sets ROADMAP as default but 3.12 requires it. Thanks about that!

Answer (score 0):

As per [Google's examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), add some CSS to make the map show at a certain size:

```
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  .map { height: 100% }
</style>
```

Try assigning the map to a variable:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(...)
```

Comment: 1. tried the css => did not change anything (as I understood so far the css is just for mobile compatibility)
2. assigning to map also did not make a change

Comment: could there be something wrong with the url scheme I use to request the api (region?)

Comment: you don't possibly have any other JS errors on the page? These will usually prevent the map displaying